# How to pass several objects to a function as parameter in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class as below that its method accept an object as its parameter.

```
template <typename T> class Matrix{
private:
    matrixNode<T>* rear=0;
    std::vector<int> rows;
    std::vector<int> cells;
    std::vector<matrixNode<T>*> listofAddedNodes;
    void generatetableRowCellArrays(int rowSize,int cellSize){
        for (int i=0;i<rowSize;i++){
            rows.push_back(i);
        }
        for (int i=0;i<cellSize;i++){
            cells.push_back(i);
        }
    }
public: 
    Matrix(int rowSize,int cellSize){
        generatetableRowCellArrays(rowSize,cellSize);
    }

    void ceateSparsMatrix(matrixNode<T> *node){
        matrixNode<T> *mxNode=(matrixNode<T>*)malloc(sizeof(matrixNode<T>));
        mxNode=node;

        if(rear!=0){
           rear->PL=(matrixNode<T>*)&rows[mxNode->line];
           rear->PC=(matrixNode<T>*)&cells[mxNode->column];
        }

        rear=mxNode;

        listofAddedNodes.push_back(mxNode);
    }

    void ceateSparsMatrix(matrixNode<T> node,int SpecificRow,int specificCell){
        matrixNode<T> *mxNode=(matrixNode<T>*)malloc(sizeof(matrixNode<T>));
        mxNode=node;
        if(rear!=0){
           rear->PL=&rows[SpecificRow];
           rear->PC=&cells[specificCell];
        }
        rear=mxNode;
        listofAddedNodesPointers.push_back(&rear->value);
    }

    void showAllAddedNodes(){
        for(int i=0;i<listofAddedNodes.size();i++){
            printf("|----------------------------|\n");
            printf("|Value   | %d                 |\n",listofAddedNodesPointers[i]->value);
            printf("|Coll    | %d                 |\n",listofAddedNodesPointers[i]->column);
            printf("|Line    | %d                 |\n",listofAddedNodesPointers[i]->line);
            printf("|PC      | %d        |\n",listofAddedNodesPointers[i]->PC);
            printf("|PL      | %d        |\n",listofAddedNodesPointers[i]->PL);
            printf("|----------------------------|\n");

        }
    }};};
```

When i want to test this function , i create several objects of the "matrixNode" class and pass to the function but it doesn't work!

```
Matrix<int> matrix(5,6);

  matrixNode<int> *matNode();
  matNode->column=2;
  matNode->line=0;
  matNode->value=2;
  matNode->PC=NULL;
  matNode->PL=NULL;

  matrixNode<int> *matNode2;
  matNode2->column=5;
  matNode2->line=5;
  matNode2->value=5;
  matNode2->PC=NULL;
  matNode2->PL=NULL;

 matrix.ceateSparsMatrix(matNode);
 matrix.ceateSparsMatrix(matNode2);
```

It doesn't pass the objects well! 
Can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: It should pass both objects to the function but it just send the first object!

Comment: In how far does it "just send the first object"?

Comment: You're not creating any objects there; you're declaring a function (giving compile errors when you try to treat it as a pointer), then creating an uninitialised pointer (giving runtime errors when you try to dereference it). Try `matrixNode<int> matNode;` if you want to create an object.

Comment: How do you know that?  Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and explain the symptoms.

Comment: I can not create matrixNode<int> matNode because my function as you can see accept pointer matrixNode<T> *node as parameter and when i don't send matrixNode<int> matNode, it shows an error

Comment: Remove all star chars and add "&" brefore (or after) parameter in the function's definition ? Pointers are to be used when there's no other possible case in c++. Always try to use references ;)

Comment: You can create pointers to objects residing anywhere in memory, you know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either dynamically allocate your matrix objects or pass pointers to existing objects.

```
Matrix<int> matrix(5,6);

  matrixNode<int> * matNode = new matrixNode<int>;
  matNode->column=2;
  matNode->line=0;
  matNode->value=2;
  matNode->PC=NULL;
  matNode->PL=NULL;

  matrixNode<int> * matNode2 = new matrixNode<int>;
  matNode2->column=5;
  matNode2->line=5;
  matNode2->value=5;
  matNode2->PC=NULL;
  matNode2->PL=NULL;

  matrixNode<int> matNode3;
  matNode3.column=5;
  matNode3.line=3;
  matNode3.value=17;
  matNode3.PC=NULL;
  matNode3.PL=NULL;

 matrix.ceateSparsMatrix(matNode);
 matrix.ceateSparsMatrix(matNode2);
 matrix.ceateSparsMatrix(&matNode3);
```

This one of your issues.